# Building a data portal

Tags: mysql

I don't if this is the right forum but I need a free application or plugin or module that I can use to pull data from mysql database and present to users on the front end. They reports should be queried by date and/or any other parameter. It should also be exported to at least CSV and maybe PDF.

Any guide will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE Web application development tool

[PHPMaker](http://www.hkvstore.com/phpmaker/)

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. I will check it out and revert back to you

Comment: I downloaded the phpmaker but it looks like it has compatibility issues with windows 10

Comment: Compatible for Windows 10